# SFINAE with VC++ compiler

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, metaprogramming, sfinae

I'm currently trying to compile a simple SFINAE structure with VC++ compiler. My version (according to the cl command) is

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24215.1 for x86
```

this code compiles fine on clang

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

struct spString
{
    template <class... T>
    spString format(T...) { return spString(); }
    const char* c_str() { return nullptr; }

    spString operator+(spString) { return spString(); }
    spString operator+(const char*) { return spString(); }
};

struct debuggable
{
    spString getDebugString() { return spString(); }
};

void fromFloat(spString, float&) {}
void fromInt(spString, int&) {}


template <class T> inline auto from( T v )
    -> decltype( v.getDebugString(), spString() )
{
    return v.getDebugString();
}
template <class T> inline auto from( T v )
    -> decltype( v->getDebugString(), spString() )
{
    spString r;
    r.format( "%u (%s)", (size_t) v, v->getDebugString().c_str() );
    return  r;
}
template <class T> inline spString from( T v )
{
    return spString("(") + typeid(T).name() + " instance)"; 
}
template <> inline spString from( float _v          ) { spString _d;  fromFloat         ( _d, _v ); return _d; }
template <> inline spString from( int _v            ) { spString _d;  fromInt           ( _d, _v ); return _d; }
//other base types

int main()
{
    debuggable x{};

    from(0);
    from(0.f);
    from(x);
}
```

but will fail on Microsoft's compiler. Noe that I can't use another version and I'm stuck with the one I'm using right now. I always had mitigated success with SFINAE on this compiler but I don't see how to easily "fix" this code.

the expected result is to get a debug string representation of something, if it has a getDebugString, use this method, if it's a base type, use a custom method, otherwise, just print the type's name.

Do you see any way to achieve that with my version of visual studio?

Comment: What are the purpose of the two first overloads? One is for method returning `spString` and the other for method returning `std::string`?

Comment: It is to handle the case where the type has a method getDebugString and use it instead of the default fallback method

Comment: Concerning edit: std::string is never mentioned, we don't use std::string for some old reasons. Also one of the methods apply on pointer or pointer like objects to an object, the other to direct instances

Comment: Did not notice that you had `.` in one case and `->` in the other - Would be better to use `T *v` in the second case for readibility.

Comment: Which version of clang are you using? I can get this code to compile with clang, which seems pretty normal since there is no way to select one of the first two overload instead of the third here.

Comment: Oh well this one is on me, let me just add a structure with a dummy getDebugString. I'll do this as soon  as I'm on a computer again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way to do what you want - tested with VC 19.00.24215.1.

**Helper template to detected `getDebugString()`:**

```
template <typename T>
auto has_getDebugString_impl(int) ->
    decltype(void(std::declval<T>().getDebugString()), std::true_type{});

template <typename T>
auto has_getDebugString_impl(...) -> std::false_type;

template <typename T>
struct has_getDebugString: decltype(has_getDebugString_impl<T>(0)) { };
```

**Combined with `std::enable_if`:**

```
template <class T>
inline std::enable_if_t < has_getDebugString<T>::value, spString > from(T v) {
    return v.getDebugString();
}

template <class T> 
inline std::enable_if_t < has_getDebugString<T>::value, spString > from(T *v) {
    spString r;
    r.format("%u (%s)", (size_t)v, v->getDebugString().c_str());
    return  r;
}
template <class T>
inline std::enable_if_t < ! has_getDebugString<T>::value, spString > from(T v) {
    return spString("(") + typeid(T).name() + " instance)"; 
}
```

**And overload (not specialized template) for specific types:**

```
inline spString from(float _v) { spString _d;  fromFloat(_d, _v); return _d; }
inline spString from(int _v) { spString _d;  fromInt(_d, _v); return _d; }
```

This is not the prettiest code, and there may be more straightforward way, but I had to deal with some issue in VC...

**Note:** You can use `enable_if` inside a default template parameter instead of as a return type if you want:

```
template <class T, class = std::enable_if_t<has_getDebugString<T>::value>>
inline spString from(T v) {
    return v.getDebugString();
}
```

Comment: thanks, sorry, I only managed to find a computer now, which is a bit late.